# Replace one field in data file with value from map file if a specific field of data file matches a key in the map

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have two files, one database and one map file, where the database file needs updating according to the map file.

`database.txt`:

```
cpe:2.3:a:adduser:adduser:3.118:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:adwaita:adwaita-icon-theme:3.36.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:aircrack:aircrack-ng:1.5.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:alsa:alsa-tools:1.2.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:amass:amass:3.7.3kali1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:amass:amass-common:3.7.3kali1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
cpe:2.3:a:amass:test:3.7.3kali1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
```

`names.txt`

```
1024cms:1024_cms
10-strike:network_monitor
10web:form_maker
10web:photo_gallery
10web:social_feed_for_instagram
1234n:minicms
12net:login_rebuilder
13thmonkey:udfclient
1kxun:qianxun_yingshi
test:test
```

I want to modify the `database.txt` such that if the 5th field is found in the second column of the map file, the 4th field should be replaced with the corresponding first column from the map file.

So, in the above example, the last line of `database.txt` contains `test` in the 5th field, which is also found in the `names.txt` file. Therefore, the 4th field of that line should be replaced with `test` and look as follows:

```
cpe:2.3:a:test:test:3.7.3kali1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
```

I tried with `awk -F:` but didn't knew how to compare values

```
awk -F: 'key[$5]; FNR==NR {key[$5]=1}'  data/database.txt data/name.txt
```

This didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following `awk` program:

```
awk -F':' -v OFS=':' 'NR==FNR{map[$2]=$1} NR>FNR && ($5 in map) {$4=map[$5]} NR>FNR' names.txt database.txt
```

This will first generate a key-value database in an associative array `map` while parsing the first file (where `NR==FNR`).

Then, when parsing the second file, it will check if the 5th field (`$5`) appears in `map`, and if so, replace the 4th field with the associated value, `map[$5]`.

It will print output lines only while processing the second file (indicated by the condition `NR>FNR` outside of action blocks).

Since both files are `:`-delimited, input and output field separators are both set to `:` (command-line options `-F':' -v OFS=':'`).